# Cast Supplier<Child> to Supplier<Parent> java

Tags: java, supplier

I have an Interface `IParent`, an abstract class implementing it `AbstractChild` and a class extending the abstract class `ConcreteChild`. One **other** class `Foo` requires an instance of a `Supplier<IParent>`.

My problem is that I have an instance of a `Supplier<ConceretChild>` and I cannot cast it to the `Supplier<IParent>` I need or just pass it straight up.

The only thing I have tried is of course:

```
((Supplier<IParent>)childSupplier)
```

Compiler says cannot cast from `Supplier<Child>` to `Supplier<Parent>`.

Comment: There is no difference between optional and supplier with respect to the generic type, hence the dupe - it's relevant, honest.

Comment: You cannot pass it directly because it's not a subtype. Generic types are not covariant. If A -> B, then Supplier<A> !-> Supplier<B>.

Comment: Yes i didn't know how to search for it. Thank you. Should i delete this? @AndyTurner

Comment: @KostasThanasis up to you. It may be useful for people searching for Supplier.

Comment: @PrashantPandey that is generally true, but in the case of Supplier, whose only method returns a T, it can also be used to return a (parent of T).